# Stencil schematic creation software

Tags: schematics

quick question, I am able to create schematics in EAGLE and other online based tools. But for the purpose of creating basic schematics, i.e. no model numbers, with basic stencil component outlines?

I have VISIO but it does not have all the required shapes, such as op-amps, or is it a case that there is no free option available?

Comment: Use the circuit tool provided with EE.SE it is free, if you would learn how to use the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a free circuit creating client. In fact, the Electrical Engineering SE has it as well! It is called [Circuit Lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)! I believe it's free to design a circuit and to run basic simulations but there are advanced features that will require a subscription.